# Linking shared library using CMake for LLVM

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, llvm

I try compile my LLVM project (shared library) with CMake.  Problems arise at the stage of linking.

I use this tutorial: http://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html#developing-llvm-passes-out-of-source

```
project_dir/
     |
     CMakeLists.txt
     <passName>/
         |
         CMakeLists.txt
         sourceFile1.cpp
         sourceFile2.cpp
         …
```

Contents of *project_dir/CMakeLists.txt:*

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.3) project(MyProjectSharedLib)
find_package(LLVM REQUIRED CONFIG)
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${LLVM_CMAKE_DIR}") 
include(AddLLVM)
message(STATUS "!!! Found LLVM ${LLVM_PACKAGE_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "!!! Using LLVMConfig.cmake in: ${LLVM_DIR}")
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
include_directories(${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_definitions(${LLVM_DEFINITIONS})
add_subdirectory(passName)
```

Contents of *project_dir/passName/CMakeLists.txt:*

```
add_llvm_loadable_module(MyProjectSharedLib
    sourceFile1.cpp
    sourceFile2.cpp
    …
)
```

After compiling and linking is created a shared library MyProjectSharedLib.so, but when I run Clang or Opt with use this library appear error:

> error: unable to load plugin
>   '/path-to-my-shared-lib/MyProjectSharedLib.so':
>   '/path-to-my-shared-lib/MyProjectSharedLib.so: undefined symbol:
>   _ZN4llvm11RuntimeDyld13MemoryManager6anchorEv'

it means that in my shared library lacks  some definition symbols.

When I add in *project_dir/passName/CMakeLists.txt:*

```
llvm_map_components_to_libnames (llvm_libs irreader x86codegen mcjit) 
target_link_libraries(MyProjectSharedLib  ${llvm_libs})
```

lines, which include to my project required libraries and eliminate dependence, then there is another error:

> CommandLine Error: Option 'x86-use-base-pointer' registered more than
>   once! fatal error: error in backend: inconsistency in registered
>   CommandLine options

I would appreciate any good advice!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I am seeing the same kind of error when linking static llvm libraries and a shared libclang-cpp.so on linux. Strangely I don't see such an error on MacOSX. The difference could be due to some difference in building with gcc on linux vs clang on Mac.